# cant git push heroku master after i tried to change one heroku domain to another heroku domain | ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment

after finishing my work i pushed code to my github, and then decided to go live through heroku. I logined to heroku, added ssh key, ran

> heroku create

but it wouldn't let me because of sqlite3. I then specified the production database to postgresql and tried again. It gave me this error.

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to thawing-refuge-61904.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/thawing-refuge-61904.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-refuge-61904.git'
```

after this i decided to just try again with the 'clean heroku domain'. so i deleted the thawing-refuge-61904 app from my heroku.

then ran

> heroku create

and tried to push again. it said

`remote: !       No such app as thawing-refuge-61904.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/thawing-refuge-61904.git/' not found`

then after doing some google research i removed remote git for thawing-refuge-61904.git (the old domain)

```
git remote rm heroku
```

and added the remote git for my new domain

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/agile-escarpment-46150.git
```

but i still get this error

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to agile-escarpment-46150.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-escarpment-46150.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-escarpment-46150.git'
```

I feel like i messed up dramatically somewhere, i need some help.

SOLVED: Okay, so the error was uo the very top that i didnt notice at first:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

This issue has been solved here: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6784#issuecomment-438562046

Just run

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2
```

And its good to go!

Comment: Please give the full push output. You're just displaying the fact that it failed here, not the actual error.

Comment: here's the build log from heroku 

https://pastebin.com/k9NgmRi1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/bundler/heroku-buildpack-bundler2
```

Solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your SSH key to heroku with `heroku keys:add`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku

Comment: try to push to heroku with  `git push -vvvvv heroku `

Answer (score 0):

Try to 
- Delete `gemfile.lock` file

- And in the gemfile, remove `gem sqlite3` or similar sqlite3 gem and add the following :

  group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
   end
  gem 'pg', group: :production

Then run these commands in the terminal:

```
bundle install
git add .
git commit
git push heroku master
```